# Ubuntu - Nvidia Drivers can't use Laptop Screen anymore

Tags: linux, ubuntu, drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

I've upgraded some time ago my nvidia drivers. The problem is, that the nvidia driver can't handle the laptop screen it self correctly anymore. This means it thinks the screen has a resolution of 640x540, but the screen stays black. All other connected screens work fine. Windows dual-boot works fine. When uninstalling nvidia or switching to nouveau or intel the laptop screen works fine.

As I said, I gave up on the problem, because back than I didn't need nvidia anymore, but now I'm forced by a Project using SteamVR to have it running.

**Details**
Currently installed nvidia driver nvidia-510-current (510.60.02);
Currently installed ubuntu 20.04 Kernel 5.13.0-28;
GraphicsCard: GP104BM [GeForce GTX 1070 Mobile]

**What I have done:**
Badly I'm not quite sure what I have done initially. I guess, I tried to upgrade nvidia. But I'm not quite sure if I had it installed from the nvidia or from the official repos. In my attempts to fix the problem, I at least reinstalled nvidia using booth ways at least once. Yesterday the I purged nvidia* and reinstalled it. And it did not help.

So what I would guess is: There is a configuration file, which was placed there manually or got orphan, which breaks any installation of nvidia. How do I find it?

Comment: Install only from the official repositories. You can use Additional drivers for that. Disable Secure Boot in UEFI and everything should work as expected.

Comment: 1. I installed from official repositories, as I pointed out.
2. I cannot modify Secure Boot settings, as I don't have the password for the UEFI Menu. So is this just a hint or what should secure boot has to do with it?

Comment: If you can't disable Secure Boot then you must use MOKutil to sicn the Nvidia proprietary drivers. Without this step the drivers are installed but Secure Boot prevents them from loading so it's the same as not having them. This are your options.

Comment: So from what I can tell, `sudo mokutil --sb-state​` tells me, that Secure Boot is already disabled.

Comment: I now reinstalled Ubuntu 20.04 fresh and the problem persists. Installed nvidia-driver-515, the screen stays black.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was finally found in the nvidia forum here: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/laptop-ubuntu-20-04-only-nativ-screen-turns-black-when-nvidia-card-takes-over-missing-edid/226503/5
Problem was that the edid was broken.

The solution was to manually add a configuration file in my home directory here: `~/.config/monitors.xml`
To make this change to the desktop manager (e.g. gdm3) I added the file also there: `/var/lib/gdm3/.config/monitors.xml`
For me it looks like this.

```
<monitors version="1">
  <configuration>
      <clone>no</clone>
      <output name="HDMI-0">
          <vendor>???</vendor>
          <product>0x0000</product>
          <serial>0x00000000</serial>
      </output>
      <output name="DP-0">
          <vendor>???</vendor>
          <product>0x0000</product>
          <serial>0x00000000</serial>
          <width>1920</width>
          <height>1080</height>
          <rate>60</rate>
          <x>0</x>
          <y>0</y>
          <rotation>normal</rotation>
          <reflect_x>no</reflect_x>
          <reflect_y>no</reflect_y>
          <primary>no</primary>
      </output>
      <output name="DP-1">
      </output>
      <output name="DP-2">
      </output>
      <output name="DP-3">
      </output>
      <output name="DP-4">
      </output>
  </configuration>
</monitors>
```

Still from time to time (e.g. at boot) the laptop screen stays black.

Comment: It could be probably useful to expand the answer to clarify how to find that vendor and other variable information (product? and serial?)